# Avalonia: Is there a ready solution for showing Dialogs (modal) in Desktop AND WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly, messagebox, avalonia

I am pretty new to Avalonia and coming from WPF and currently stucking in providing modal dialogs (e.g. with YES/NO-option for user). Already tried different nuget packages like Avalonia.MessageBox (and MessageBoxSlim) but stucking at getting it to work for the WebAssembly-Part, Desktop-side its working.

Is there maybe a ready solution for using both variants - or do you maybe have a hint how to do this correctly?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DialogHost.Avalonia](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DialogHost.Avalonia/)

Comment: Having no method such as `await MessageBox.ShowAsync("Title", "Content", buttons, icon, etc...)` makes me not consider this for my next native UI project. Why everything these days must be so half-backed and complicated?